# NSUrl is not stored as absolutestring in NSUserDefault

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsurl, datastore

I am referring [Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818532/iphone-save-url-without-seturlforkey-and-nsurl) for storing NSURL of iPod Library in NSUserDefault. But it is not stored in NSUserDefault after application is closed.

I am using other NSStrings to store in NSUserDefaults which is perfectly done, But when i store NSUrl as absolute string.. it does not stores the value.

What could be the reason??

**EDIT**

Following code i am using to save NSUserDefault Value:

```
currentItem = [collection.items objectAtIndex:songCount];
songURL = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] forKey:@"songTitle"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[songURL absoluteString] forKey:@"songURL"];
avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:songURL];
NSLog(@"songTitle: %@  songURL : %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"songTitle"], songURL);
```

Following error comes when i try to save the NSURL:

```
2011-09-13 18:47:23.258 Tabata Timer[933:707] songURL : ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-3715406019015217536
2011-09-13 18:47:23.258 Tabata Timer[933:707] *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value 'ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-3715406019015217536' of class 'NSURL'.
2011-09-13 18:47:23.260 Tabata Timer[933:707] songTitle : Ghajini
2011-09-13 18:47:24.860 Tabata Timer[933:707] *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value 'ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-3715406019015217536' of class 'NSURL'.
2011-09-13 18:47:24.963 Tabata Timer[933:707] songURL : ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-3715406019015217536
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

Comment: Could we see a few lines of code where you store the url? Also, when you say it does not store the value, I assume the particular string stored is simply nil? Any warnings on your code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to store NSURL then why are you converting it into string and saving it as string. It will increase your work effort.

You can try this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];     
[defaults setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] forKey:@"urlValue"];
[defaults synchronize];

NSURL *url=[defaults URLForKey:@"urlValue"];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
```

Comment: Why to use [defaults synchronize] ??

Comment: Actually this methods automatically calls at periodic intervals and update data automatically but in the mean while if it not updated and if you use it you will get the old results not the modified so it is manually called so that you can make your data saved immediately .

Comment: instead of [NSURL URLWithString:..] i am using [url absoluteURL] where url is my NSURL...

Comment: what is use of this [url absoluteURL].If url is of NSURL type  so you just have to do [defaults setURL:url forKey:@"urlValue"];

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that would explain it is that the URL is at least partially randomly generated and thus fails to load after you app removes reference to it. What do you mean, "closed"? Backgrounded? Or really terminated?

It could also be that you should be saving it as a `string:yourURLString forKey:@"URL"` instead of an object. It could be confusing the app. Try `NSLog` to output the URL string and see what you get. Let me know what it is. That will clarify things.

Comment: i have added the code and error. Also Every time my app starts from beginning. I don't allow my app to be in background, it will always starts as new.

Answer (score 0):

your string should have property declared...then try to store it in `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: try to create an instance of NSURL and create a property and synthesize it and then try to store ...