# Saving Videos to NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I want save video files in NSUserDefaults..I know there is a way  we can save through setURL in UserDefault.How to add URL in a Array ??

Comment: You can't add video files to `NSUserDefaults`. You could add a URL to a video, but not the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add URLs in an array, and save the array in NSUserDefaults

```
NSArray *urlArray = @[url1, url2, url3];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:urlArray forKey:@"UrlArrayKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411508/nsurl-is-not-stored-as-absolutestring-in-nsuserdefault  pls refer the above link and proceed with answer..thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

```
//store urls in NSUserDefaults
NSArray *arrayURLsToStore = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"link1", "link2", nil];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayURLsToStore forKey:@"URLs"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//get urls from NSUserDefaults
NSArray *arrURLsRetrived = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"URLs"];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:[arrURLsRetrived objectAtIndex:0]];
NSURL *youURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//now you can use URL1
```

Comment: if I store URL in NSUSERDEFAULT there is crash "Attempt to insert non-property value"

Comment: Convert URLs in NSString and then store in UserDefault.

Comment: I tried that too,when i convert to NSString and Retrieve it back to NSURL the video file is not displaying ..but URL is present

Comment: log that url in console and try to open in browser to check it is opening or not.

Comment: copy that path...open Finder -> Press cmd+shift+G -> Paste path -> press enter...if path is correct then you'll find video otherwise not.

Comment: I am sorry I have to be more specific...the file path is from the simulator not from the system

Comment: This is just a way that to verify that whether it is valid path or not !!

Comment: I mean if i save from iphone...then how will i check

Comment: Apple provide simulators to check...so first try on simulator. If it work fine then definitely work on iphone as well.

Comment: I am saving live videos so i can only check from iphone

Answer (score 0):

The user defaults are a property list. According to the [specifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303) only a few types build property lists.

- `NSArray`
- `NSDictionary`
- `NSString`
- `NSNumber`
- `NSData`
- `NSDate`

Collections (array dictionary) are property lists, if and only if all of their members are property lists.

As you can see from the link, `NSURL` is no property list. But you can convert an instance of `NSURL` into a instance of `NSString` (URL string) at write time …:

```
NSString *URLString = [URL absoluteString];
```

… and store this into the array (which stays being a property list, because instances of `NSString` are property lists).

At read time you can take out the string from the array and convert it back into an instance of `NSURL`:

```
NSURL* URL = [NSURL UrlWithString:URLString];
```

Another way is to convert the instance of `NSURL` into an instance of `NSData` and back. This is possible, because `NSURL` supports `NS`(`Secure`)`Coding`.

Comment: but UserDefault has a property [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setURL];

Comment: Do you mean `-setURL:forKey:` (`NSUserDefaults`)? Did you read the documentation, what this method does? Exactly what I described in my answer.

Comment: My requirement is to save video in NSUserDefault..Your answer had fetched me the url but its not displaying the video content

Comment: It was quite unclear whether you want to save the video or the url of the video. However, having the url you can read the video. If you really want to store the video you can do exactly the same thing: Encode it to an instance of `NSData` and store that. But user defaults are definetly no place to store a video.